# Not able to use Node.js and Crontab

Tags: node.js, npm, cron

I know that you can run a Node.js script in Crontab by doing something like:

```
0 * * * * node /path/to/your/script.js
```

But I want to run a Node.js app, not a script, using Crontab. I created a Node.js app in order to write some automated tests using Mocha, Chai and Selenium, and I want to run it periodically by using Crontab. How would I go about doing this? I currently run my app by writing in the command line:

```
npm run api-pro
```

Where api-pro is a script from my package.json that invokes some tests for the production api.

Note that if I simply try to write a Crontab job with the command "npm run api-pro" it doesn't recognize the command npm (and obviously I do have Node installed in my computer).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My guess is that the user `cron` use do not configure the `PATH` in the same way as your user, and do not know `node` nor `npm`.

What you can try is to use the command `which node` to know where your node binary is (`/some/path/to/node`)

Then you can use the absolute path in your crontab:

```
0 * * * * /some/path/to/node /path/to/your/script.js
```

EDIT:

The difference between adding `node` and `npm` to `$PATH` and using absolute paths is that absolute path will work for one executable, since Linux will not have to search the `PATH`.
Adding to the `PATH` will make Linux recognize `node` and `npm` just as in your user. The fact that they are in the same folder do not affect that.

Comment: Ok so if I do this for node, it now recognizes the node command, but it does not recognize the npm command. I don't see how this is possible since my npm and node are both in the same path /usr/local/bin. So if I do /usr/local/bin/node -v in crontab it works fine and gives me the version, but if I do /usr/local/bin/npm -v I get the error "env: node: no such file or directory". Any thoughts?

Comment: I was able to fix it by adding my $PATH value to Cron's PATH. Not really sure how this is any different from specifying the path of npm in the Cron's command (/usr/local/bin/npm), but it works.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone trying to run with `npm`, here were my steps to get it working on MacOS 12.3.1, using `node`/`npm` installed by brew.

*Note, this is inflexible, and the PATH will need to be updated if brew updates its paths again:*

1. Print two things we will need

```
echo $PATH
// /opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:...

which npm
// /opt/homebrew/bin/npm
```

2. Open crontab with `EDITOR="vim" crontab -e`
3. Add these two lines

```
PATH={what you copied from step 1}
* * * * * cd {your_project_dir_where_package.json_lives} && {location_of_npm_from_step_1} run start >>/tmp/crontab.log 2>&1
```

---

*Note: The `>>/tmp/crontab.log 2>&1` is to help you debug. You can `tail -f /tmp/crontab.log` in another terminal to watch for STDOUT or STDERR*

Answer (score 1):

I guess that by using crontab, you're running your node app on a Linux machine so why don't you write a simple bash script ?

**run_test.bash**

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /path/to/your/app && \
npm run api-pro
```

then your crontab should look like :

```
0 * * * * /path/to/your/bash/script/run_test.bash
```

Of course, your script will have to be executable for your user :

```
$ chmod u+x run_test.bash
```

Comment: Is the \ after the && in the script a typo or why is there?

Comment: This doesn't resolve the initial issue, this is just another way of writing what I had already wrote and it gives me the error "/bin/sh npm: command not found". I'm starting to think that it doesn't recognize npm because it's trying to run it at /bin/sh. Do you have any idea as to how to change this so that it runs somewhere in my computer where it can recognize npm? Npm is installed in my computer and I can use it perfectly in the Terminal.

Comment: the `&& \` is not a typo, it's just to check the path exists before calling the script.

Comment: If I run the commands directly in Crontab (without a bash script) I get "/bin/sh npm: command not found" and using the bash script I get "path/to/script: line 3: npm: command not found"

Comment: It runs correctly on my computer, I've edited a simple crontab with my user to run `npm -v` each minute and it's ok, I don't have the `command not found` error. Could it be possible the crontab was edited with a user that doesn't have the right to run npm ?

Comment: And you do see an output of the npm version? No, since I'm editing the crontab and I can run npm on my terminal just fine. I think it's what I told you about the /bin/sh folder, but I'm not sure how to fix that. For example, if I type an invalid command in my terminal I get the error "bash xxx: command not found", note that it's bash and not /bin/sh. I'm not entirely sure what this means, but logically I think npm is recognized in bash and not in /bin/sh.

Comment: yes I see it because the entire command was `* * * * * npm -v > /tmp/test.txt`.

Comment: Your solution is returning the following error:
`npm: command not found`